# SwiftUI NavigationLink for row

Tags: swiftui

I have this:

```
ForEach(item, id: \.name) { _ in
    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
        ItemCell(item: $0)
    }
}
```

But it's throwing an error saying:

```
Unnamed argument #2 must precede argument 'destination'
```

All the documentation I've seen so far seems to be following what I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you wanted this

```
ForEach(item, id: \.name) { el in
    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
        ItemCell(item: el)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that did it... was this recently changed? I'm running Xcode 12.2 running on an iOS 14.2 simulator. All the examples I saw had what I had originally.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the API changed. This worked:

```
NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(), label: {
    ItemCell(item: item)
})
```